# Neo4j: Actors who have acted in 40+ movies?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have just started learning neo4j.

I am kind of stuck with creating this query.

Query: How many actors have acted in 10 or more movies?

Picture below shows the schema:

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MATCH (a:Actor)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH a, count(m) AS movie_count
WEHRE movie_count > 40
RETURN a
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have larger relationship-counts you might use the node degree directly, which is more efficient.

```
MATCH (a:Actor)
WHERE size( (a)-[:ACTS_IN]->() ) > 40
RETURN a
```